# Project build error: Non-parseable POM /pom.xml: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_TAG seen ...)

Tags: java, maven, web-services, spring-boot, pom.xml

I am consuming a SOAP web service using Spring Boot. To convert WSDL to Java Binding(Domain) classes I am using `maven-jaxb2-plugin`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
        <generatePackage>com.test.consume</generatePackage>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <url>https://test.co.in/cordys/WSDLGateway.wcp?service=http://schemas.cordys.com/default/getIDV&organization=o=B2C,cn=cordys,cn=defaultInst106,o=mydomain.com</url>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

> In `<url>` tag I have written the WSDL URL like this

```
<url>https://test.co.in/cordys/WSDLGateway.wcp?service=http://schemas.cordys.com/default/getIDV&organization=o=B2C,cn=cordys,cn=defaultInst106,o=mydomain.com</url>
```

> But I am getting the following issue with pom.xml

`Project build error: Non-parseable POM /home/altaf/My Workspace/TestConsumer/pom.xml: entity reference name can not contain character 
 =' (position: START_TAG seen ...wcp?service=http://schemas.cordys.com/default/getIDV&organization=... @64:117)`

> How to resolve this issue?

Comment: `<url>https://test.co.in/cordys/WSDLGateway.wcp?service=http://schemas.cordys.com/default/getIDV&organization=o=B2C,cn=cordys,cn=defaultInst106,o=mydomain.com></url>` has some problems: you have an extra `>` character, and you don't escape `&` characters. The file should contain valid xml

Comment: Replace `&` with `&amp;`

Comment: The extra `>`...should be removed...

Comment: Yes I agree it's my mistake to put extra `>` but my problem is solved by this one 

**Replace & with &amp;**

Thanks

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem with `&` inside xml node. Solved by replacing `&` with `&amp;` as @ygor suggested in comment.

Posting this as an answer for better visibility.